# Creating two objects with same name in Java

Tags: java

I have a class name `Planet` and I am making objects in main.

```
Planet planet1 = new Planet("High Temperature","No Water);
Planet planet2 = new Planet("Low Temperature","Ice");
```

However, I saw my instructor doing this:

```
Planet planet1 = new Planet("High Temperature","No Water);
       planet1 = new Planet("Low Temperature","Ice");
```

So basically, my instructor is also creating two objects. I understand that a new object is basically formed when constructor is called but I always thought that the two objects need to have distinct names as well.

As you can see above, there are two objects created using the name `planet1`.

Also, is there any difference in creating two objects with the two different ways mentioned above.

Comment: It's just that the variable to hold object reference is one but two object will be created nonetheless. Second assignment will replace the reference with new object's

Comment: planet1 is just a reference. He is creating a new object and referencing it. [Using Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)

Comment: I think you can ask this question to your instructor as well. :) The answers you may get here would be full of jargons..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, you are creating two distinct instances of the `Planet` class. In the second case, you assign your high-temperature planet to the variable `planet1`, and then create a new planet (low temperature), assigning it to the same variable (`planet1`), discarding a reference to your earlier high-temperature planet. Java's garbage collector, realizing that this first planet is no longer reachable, deletes it from the heap, reclaiming its memory.

In the first case, you have two distinct Planet objects and two distinct variables of type `Planet`, each storing a reference to one of the two objects.

Answer (score 1):

> `Planet planet1=new Planet("High Temperature","No Water);
>   Planet planet2= new Planet("Low Temperature","Ice");`

In the above example you have two different object references namely planet1 and planet2.

```
Planet planet1=new Planet("High Temperature","No Water);
planet1 = new Planet("Low Temperature","Ice");
```

Here you have only one object reference planet1 that's accessible. When the second line is executed the reference of the first object is no longer available since it has been over written with the second object's reference.

Answer (score 0):

The way you approached object instantiation creates two variables (planet1 and planet2) with references to two distinct Planet objects. These objects can be accessed by other operations.

The instructor's approach first instantiates a Planet object referenced by the variable planet1. Then the reference is discarded, and set to point to a newly constructed Planet object. In this case, only the planet with low temperature and ice is accessible. The previous Planet object with high temperature and No water can no longer be accessed.